# Select ALL from many postgres tables

Tags: postgresql

We have around 40 tables, all with similar, but not identical fields.  Each table has `created_by` and `created_at` fields.

We're trying to query a specific set of tables, and return only the `created_at` fields from rows `created_by = 'john'`

So far, we've got

```sql
select created_at from results_tables

where <TABLE_NAME> in
(
   select table_name from information_schema.tables 
   where <some criteria to limit tables being searched>
)
and created_by = 'john'
```

The inner query works on its own, and lists the correct tables.
We want the outer query to get `created_at` from ALL the tables in the inner query.

So from the following tables:

```
table1
created_by   created_at val
john         12:00      5
sue          13:20      7

table20
created_by   created_at val
john         21:30      3
jane         23:45      21
```

we'd get:

```
12:00
21:30
```

Comment: You need to write a function that uses dynamic SQL for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function which will be accessing all your tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_schema.some_function_name()
returns TABLE(created_by varchar(300), created_at varchar(300))
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  stmt text;
  BEGIN
    stmt = (
        WITH relevant_tables AS (
           SELECT table_name,
                  CONCAT('SELECT created_by::varchar(300), created_at::varchar(300) FROM ', table_name) as table_query
           FROM information_schema.tables 
           WHERE <some criteria to limit tables being searched>
        )
        SELECT string_agg(table_query, ' UNION ALL ') AS final_query
        FROM relevant_tables a
    );
    return query EXECUTE stmt;
  end; $BODY$
language plpgsql
;
```

I do not know what are your data types so I casted everything to `varchar(300)`.

Having this function, you can then call:

```
SELECT * FROM some_schema.some_function_name()
```

You can also add any `WHERE` you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
do $$
DECLARE
i record;
xcreated_at text;

BEGIN

FOR i in  select table_name from information_schema.tables  LOOP

EXECUTE('select created_at from '||i.table_name||' where created_by = ''John''')INTO xcreated_at;
raise notice 'xcreated_at%',xcreated_at;
END LOOP;
END;

$$  ;
```